# sfml 2.4.1 memory leaks

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sfml

I use SFML-2.4.1, MSVS2015, I have last NVIDIA Card (378.49) and this program has memory leaks (noticeable when working within >5 minutes):

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    Image image;
    image.create(200, 200);
    while (1)
    {
        Texture t;
        t.loadFromImage(image);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And this code hasn't it:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    Image image;
    image.create(200, 200);
    Texture t;
    while (1)
    {
        t.loadFromImage(image);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Is it a problem in `sf::Texture::~Texture()`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really reproduce this issue and I don't see any way this should happen. Maybe it's some driver bug and/or setting possibly in combination with your graphics card model?

Compiled your snippet with MSVC 2017 RC as x64 and the program is pretty constant at 24 MB memory usage no matter how long it's running (same driver version on a GTX 1080).

Try to compile the latest source code version and see if this changes anything.